# How to make specific <div> show if checkbox with specific name is checked off?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Stepper element, and the first `<mat-step>` contains a list of checkboxes for the user to check.

The following is the first `<mat-step>` with the checkboxes:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="itemCheckboxes">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Select The Items You Want</ng-template>
  <span *ngIf="items.length === 0">No items currently in your account.</span>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none; padding-left: 0px;">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      <mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, item.name)">{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
  </div>
</mat-step>
```

I'm trying to make a specific `<div>` show in a following `<mat-step>`, only if checkboxes with specific `{{item.name}}`s are checked.

For example, if the user checks a checkbox named "Banana", then the specific `<div>` related to the checked "Banana" checkbox would show. And if the user checks a checkbox named "Apple", then a different `<div>` would show.

How would I write the code to achieve this? I am trying to edit an existing project, and I am very new to coding, but I need to get this done quickly, so step-by-step details would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need understand "Angular philosophy". Angular correlation the variables in .ts (the model) with the elements in html (the view)

So if you declare a variable

```
myvariable:boolean=true
```

And you checkbox is

```
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myvariable">Banana</mat-checkbox>
```

The [(ngModel)] relation in two direction -binding two ways- the variable and the check-box. If you check the checkbox, the variable becomes true, if you uncheck the chackbox, the variable becomes false.

So you can write in anywhere

```
<div *ngIf="myvariable">
   If you see this is because the checkbox is true
</div>
```

Well you has an array of "items", so if you make a binding -use [(ngModel)] to a variable

```
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
```

You can write

```
<div *ngIf="items[0].checked">
   You check the first element of the list before
</div>
```

**Update** if we want to know if "Banana" is checked

Well, I suppose we has an array of object

```
items=[{name:"Banana"},{name:"apple"},{name:"orange"}...]
```

When checked one or more we convert the array in some like

```
items=[{name:"Banana",checked:true},{name:"apple"},{name:"Orange",checked:false}...]
```

See that one or more elements can has no property "checked"

a function like

```
isSelect(fruit:string)
{
    return this.items.find(x=>x.checked && x.name==fruit)!=null
}
```

return true or false. Now you has several options:

1.-Using a getter

```
get isBananaSelected()
{
    return this.isSelect("Banana")
}
```

And use in ngIf

```
   <div *ngIf="isBananaSelected">...</div>
```

2.-Use an auxiliar variable that calcule when the stepper change the step

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">

isVisibleDiv:boolean=false //and auxiliar variable
selectionChange(event)
{
  if (event.selectedIndex==1){ //remember the index is 0 for the first step, 1 for the second...
      this.isVisibleDiv=this.isSelect("Banana")
  }
}

//and 
<div *ngIf="isVisibleDiv">...</div>
```

3.-Use an auxiliar variable and call the function each change in a select

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="isVisibleDiv=this.isSelect("Banana")">
```

NOTE: It's looks like that a getter is the best bet, but be carefull, a getter is executed several times, the second option only execute when change the step and the third option executed each change in any check-box. (really for simplex functions -like in this case- you has not note a better or worst performance), but we need choose between simply and performance

Comment: Thank you! However with this solution, the <div> would show based on the first element of the list. I understand you can change the number in <div *ngIf="items[0].checked"> to adjust which element of the list to base it on, but how would you make it show based on the name instead? Because I want a specific <div> to show only if "Banana" was checked, regardless of where it is on the list.

Comment: I update the answer show three ways to do it, you need choose one of them

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-template` & `ngTemplateOutlet`. Here is the [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lurbdk). The example shown only the showing of the template. When checkbox is unchecked the template reference can be removed from the array

```
import {
  Component,
  TemplateRef,
  VERSION,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  templates = [];
  items = [{
      name: "Banana"
    },
    {
      name: "Apple"
    },
    {
      name: "Orange"
    },
    {
      name: "Brinjal"
    }
  ];
  @ViewChild("Banana") Banana: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild("Apple") Apple: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild("Orange") Orange: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild("Brinjal") Brinjal: TemplateRef < any > ;
  onCheckboxChange(event, name) {
    this.templates.push(this[name]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-template matStepLabel>Select The Items You Want</ng-template>
<span *ngIf="items.length === 0">No items currently in your account.</span>
<ul style="list-style-type:none; padding-left: 0px;">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, item.name)">{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
  </li>
</ul>
<div>
  <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let tmpl of templates">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tmpl"></ng-container>
</div>


<ng-template #Banana>
  <span>Banana</span></ng-template>

<ng-template #Apple>
  <span>Apple</span></ng-template>

<ng-template #Orange>
  <span>Orange</span></ng-template>

<ng-template #Brinjal>
  <span>Brinjal</span></ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you @brk but for some reason this doesn't work when I use the code in my app. I think it's because I already have a "onCheckboxChange($event, item.name)" function for the checkboxes that would contradict with the one you provided? Also, how would I write "Yellow Banana" in the "@ViewChild" function since it's more than 1 word?

Comment: try like this `YellowBanana`